# @ngrx with API, how do I recognise differences in results?

Tags: angular, laravel, api, state, ngrx

I've stumbled into a problem and I feel that it's getting worse as time goes. The problem I'm having is that API-calls might give same results but with slightly different attributes, and I'm having a problem to figure out how to implement this with @ngrx.

Example:

- We've got a user role: `system user`.

  - Non-logged-in-users uses `/api/activities` to fetch activities.
  - `System user` uses `/api/su/activities` to fetch activities.
  - Both API-calls return activities but one of them also returns an attribute `activity_categories`.
- Before `SU` is logged in they fetch activities with `/api/activities` and the result is stored in the store.
- Then `SU` logs in and now needs the extra data to each activity (activity_categories) and checks if the activities are already fetched. If they are it skips the API call (`/api/su/activities`).
- `SU` now gets an error because each activity is missing their categories (activity['activity_categories']).

So, is there a smart way to get round this? :)

Comment: I suggest you predefine activity_categories as null in your object then if the guy logs in, you can assign the value to this variable

Comment: @Ricardo The problem that i stated above is that it does not even do the other api-call because the first fetch of activities already is in the store.

Comment: @RamoMislimi don't you have control over the store?

Comment: why not clean the store by setting the initial state again after log in... Is like execute 2 operations, clean the store, execute rest call

Comment: @Ricardo I thought about that too and it's a possible solution. But it not a possible solution if you should be able to visit both pages when logged in. I could block the user from going to the page where the `/api/activities` is made, but it's no good solution. One option is to make a similar page but with the other api-call (`/api/su/activities`).

Comment: Can you refactor the API calls into `/api/activities` and `/api/su/activitycategories` then enrich the data already in the state with the activity category data? Then on the SU page, in the case where the `/api/activities` data is already present, you just do the second call, in the case where it is not present, you do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to this. The simplest is to ignore the fact that these are "the same" data and store the two different sets of activity data, one enriched, one not, in the state store as completely separate things.

The other option would be to refactor the API to provide an endpoint which just returns the extra category data for the activities (e.g. `/api/su/activitiycategories`), then call just that second endpoint if you already have the base activity data in the state. You'd then update the state data with the extra category data.

You may need to store a flag in the state (e.g. "activitiesEnrichedWithCategories") to control whether you need to do that call or not. In the case where the base activities do not exist, you would then need to do both calls to get the enriched data or call the `/api/su/activitycategories/` endpoint instead.

This second option is far more complex to implement, but if there are lots of activities, it might be worth the extra effort.

Comment: I agree, the second one if far more complex. Maybe it's possible to do a general solution for this, maybe so I can specify when using `select(x)` to fetch, to also specify what types of values I need it to have, and if it doesn't it does the fetch (as you mentioned) to fetch the extra data and populate the already stored data. But it feels lika one hell of a mess to do something like this and time consuming. I think I'll just separate them into their own state (`su-activities` and `activities`). Thanks for the help. I'm no expert in @ngrx and just didn't know if I was missing something else.

Comment: @RamoMislimi There are ways of doing what you describe, for sure, but i'm not sure that it's the best structure. Another cleaner solution would be to subscribe to your activitiies via select(x), then in your controller, if you detect that you do not have the enriched data, fire off the request to get it and put that in the state. The controller will then automatically receive the updated data. If you wanted to ensure that the component template did not receive the data until the categories are populated, you could put a filter on. I can write that up as another answer if it sounds plausible?

Comment: That fine, I think I'll go with the less complex solution where I have a separate state (or even store) for each user role. When thinking about these solution I think the less complex one is easier to scale and will cause less headache, especially if other developers are going to work with the code. Thanks for the help and great answer :)